# AIX 5.3 snmp configuration for CPU and Memory monitoring

Tags: snmp, aix

is there a way to do this with normal snmpd of AIX53 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the number of people asking for this around the net and the fact that all the answers seem to point them off to other packages like [Big Brother](http://www.bb4.org/) or [RMC](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246615.html) ([docs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/rzaig/rzaigrmc.htm)) or other solutions, there might not be. Maybe somebody here will prove me wrong. Kolay gelsin.

Comment: with cacti I took cpu one by one via snmp but the there is no total load avarage of cpus. anyway I watch my servers with ssh and they are ok to push little bit further :) eyvallah

Answer (score 0):

As I recall you have to enable hostmibd access. Which version of snmpd are you using? 5.3 supports snmpdv1 and snmpdv3.